# Importar palabra clave en el programa Python

Tags: python

¿Cómo sabe el sistema operativo cómo manejar la palabra clave "importar" en un programa de python? En otras palabras, ¿cómo sabe el módulo referido cómo "importar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El sistema operativo no tiene nada qué ver en el proceso de importación.

El intérprete python tiene una serie de complicadas reglas acerca de cómo interpretar la palabra reservada `import`. En esencia se trata de que, cuando encuentra `import nombre`, busca un archivo llamado `nombre.py` (o una carpeta llamada `nombre`, que contenga en su interior un fichero llamado `__init__.py`) en una serie de carpetas preconfiguradas y en otras que se le puedan especificar mediante `PYTHONPATH`.

La historia completa es [mucho más larga y complicada](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), pero mejor editas la pregunta y añades dudas más concretas si es que necesitas saber más.

PD: Si tienes tres horas libres puedes ver este [video de David Beazly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0) donde te explica todos los entresijos, probablemente *mucho más* de lo que necesitas (o querrías) saber. Yo aún no entiendo la mitad...